# How can I retry a function with try/catch promise in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I need help with a performative way to retry if the return is 500, to try again

What would be the most viable solution in this case?

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCSV(createPayload())
    ;(async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoadingGraph(true)
        const response = await api.generateDataByFilters(createPayload())
        response.data.itens.forEach((data) => {
          setDataTable(data.detail)
          setDataGraph(data.summarizedBySenderNumber)
          setTotalDispatchMessages(data.totalDispatchMessages)
          setTotalSentMessages(data.totalSentMessages)
          setTotalReceivedMessages(data.totalReceivedMessages)
          setTotalReadMessages(data.totalReadMessages)
          setTotalFailedMessages(data.totalFailedMessages)
          setTotalBillableMessages(data.totalBillableMessages)
        })
        setIsLoadingGraph(false)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    })()
  }, [periodFilter, originFilter, senderFilter, endDateTime, initialDateTime])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the function a name, then in the catch method, if the `status === 500`, re-execute the function again, Also you can give a throttling between each request by for example 2 seconds.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setCSV(createPayload())
    const generateDataByFilters = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoadingGraph(true)
        const response = await api.generateDataByFilters(createPayload())
        response.data.itens.forEach((data) => {
          setDataTable(data.detail)
          setDataGraph(data.summarizedBySenderNumber)
          setTotalDispatchMessages(data.totalDispatchMessages)
          setTotalSentMessages(data.totalSentMessages)
          setTotalReceivedMessages(data.totalReceivedMessages)
          setTotalReadMessages(data.totalReadMessages)
          setTotalFailedMessages(data.totalFailedMessages)
          setTotalBillableMessages(data.totalBillableMessages)
        })
        setIsLoadingGraph(false)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        if (error.status === 500) {
          await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                generateDataByFilters()
                resolve()
            }, 2000)
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }, [periodFilter, originFilter, senderFilter, endDateTime, initialDateTime])
```